# Google Sheet extract first value from cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a bunch of values, and I need to set next column values equal to the first value. However, the values may look different. Here is an example

```
A1 = 8812
A2 = 26128
A3 = 16113], [18712]
A4 = 234
```

I need the first numerical value, no matter the length or following characters.

B values should therefore be

```
B1 = 8812
B2 = 26128
B3 = 16113
B4 = 234
```

I can't come up with a solution. The length of the values are different, so I can't just pick the first "4" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GS you could use:

```
=--REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(A1,"@"),"\d+")
```

### Reference

[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

[TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)